# How can I know application startup time?

Tags: ios, objective-c

How can I find out what time the application was launched (Since the beginning of the show Splash Screen.)?

If we use:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:    (NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
```

In this case time spent on showing Splash screen is not considered.

Tried to use:

```
NSDate *startTime = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:clock()/CLOCKS_PER_SEC];
```

But it returns an incorrect value.

Any idea how I can find the correct value?

Comment: you mean the application is ready to take input from user or as soon as user clicks the launch button?

Answer (score 4):

Register the start time either in your app `main` function or in the application delegate `init` method.

Then in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` take current time and subtract them.

Comment: The main function is called with some delay.

For example on the 3GS runs 5 seconds before calling main.

Comment: @2Grey Unfortunately, there is no way to do something sooner. The application has to load into memory before it's started and that takes some time. If it's not started, you can't do anything.

Comment: In app we can get the process ID of the application.

But can we get (from the system) launch time of process by ID?

Comment: @2Grey http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16366701/is-it-possible-to-get-the-launch-time-of-pid

Answer (score 1):

You can use Instruments (from Xcode - Product -> Profile or CMD+I). You can use the Time Profiler there. The description of the Time Profiler: `Performs low-overhead time-based sampling of processes running on the system's CPUs`. Plus you can see a timeframe with any template.

If you **have** to do it in your code, you can use @Sulthan suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

In Time Profiler, Expand the call tree (Main Thread -> start -> main -> … -> [appdelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:]). In the Running Time column you will find the time taken info.